# SQL Server : ALTER TABLE tablename SWITCH PARTITION 2 to tempempty

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, alter-table

Have a sliding partition where I need to remove the trailing partition when they expire. I create an empty table that matches the existing table. When I create the empty table, I specify the file group that I am going to be removing. I also create all the indexes on the empty table so it matches exactly the data table on that partition.

Once the empty table and indexes are created, I issue the command

```
alter table mydatatable switch partition 2 to emptytable
```

The command takes forever to run and after reading everything I could about the switching, I thought it was only moving meta data over and a very quick step.

My plan is to swap the data to the empty one and then truncate the empty table and remove the file group.

To add a little more details. The data table started off as a non-partitioned table. Due to the number of r5ecords in it, we had to partition it. So I created the partition schema, function and all of the file groups. I dropped the clustered index and all other indexes and recreated them all. The partition process looks to be successful.

When I run the alter table command, it feels like there is data being transferred and not just meta data.

Comment: Locking issue. sp_who2. Who is blocking your switch?

Comment: [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx) is far better than sp_who2 :-)